# Routing Issues in rails 2

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I recently created a model named setting. now in the settings page, i have all these collections for the settings. But when i try to save it, it says that NameError in SettingsController: uninitialized constant SettingsController! I know this concerns the route of the object, which is "map.resource :settings". That's why it redirects to locahost:3000/settings (which is non-existent). how can i change the route so that i can also change the url it redirects to? thanks! need this soooooo badly!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`:controller` option in 2.3](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/v2.3.8/routing.html#using-controller):

```
map.resources :settings, :controller => 'what_ever_you_want'
```

or the [`:as` option](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/v2.3.8/routing.html#using-as) to change the path:

```
map.resources :settings, :as => 'some_other_path'
```

The `:controller` changes the controller class so the above would use `WhatEverYouWantController`. The `:as` changes the path so the above would use `/some_other_path/new`, `/some_other_path/11`, etc.

Comment: thanks for the response. but i am still getting an error. Unknown action "create". :( and when i check it, still doesn't save anything :(

Comment: @Aldrin: Does your controller have all the usual methods for a RESTful controller?

Comment: i don't have a controller for settings.

Comment: @Aldrin: Routes route things to controllers, you need a controller or nothing useful will happen. Am I missing something here?

Comment: i have controller named xero. those settings are supposed to map settings for data to be sent via xero API. I was expecting that i can use that setting and save it to the database. that's all.

Comment: @Aldrin: You need to add more detail to your question.

Comment: you're right, mu. I have no problem with xero. I just need to save the settings to the database. that's all.